# how to calculate residuals in r

Tags: r, lm

I want to calculate the residuals for different gender.

my regression looks like this

```
lm.fit7 <- lm(average_intp.trust ~ age + v225 , data=S_intp.trust, na.action = na.exclude)
```

I then calculate the residuals

```
intp.trust$residuals <-resid(lm.fit7)
```

I have used `ggplot` to map the distribution of the residuals

```
ggplot(S_intp.trust, aes(x=age, y=residuals7, color=as.factor(v225)))+
  geom_point()
```

but my graphs doesn't seems right

[image]

I am very confused about what to put in the x-axis in the `ggplot()` to calculate the residuals.

Thank you!

Comment: both your age and residuals7 column look like they could be categorical (and not numeric). Are they? What does running `str` on your data show? What are the classes of the variables?

Comment: hi, age looks like this ```> str(S_intp.trust$age)
 dbl+lbl [1:8922] 27, 58, 43, 25, 42, 23, 82, 51, 43, 80, 30, 76, 52, 52, 57, 20, 64, 62, 80, 39, 45, 31, 47, 45, 3...
 @ label       : chr "age: respondent (constructed) (Q64)"
 @ format.stata: chr "%8.0g"
 @ labels      : Named num [1:11] -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:11] "multiple answers Mail" "no follow-up" "follow-up non response" "matrix not applied" ...
````

Comment: and residuals looks like this.         > str(S_intp.trust$residuals7)
 Factor w/ 133 levels "-1.62652563303392e-11",..: 1 77 107 92 57 128 28 91 55 4 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:8922] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...

Comment: okay. so you can see that your residuals is not numeric. You have somehow managed to convert the results of `resid(lm.fit7)` to a factor. Your `age` variable also looks weird although this might just be labels so would be okay. So first step is to fix your residuals vector.

Comment: hi, I have used 'fitted values' to replace 'age', and 'as.numeric' to convert 'resid(lm.fit7)'. I think it works now. Thank you!

Comment: good you got it working. You shouldn't have to convert `resid(lm.fit7)` as it will be numeric ; It likely happened when you formed the `residuals7` variable from `intp.trust$residuals <-resid(lm.fit7)`